# Redirect all traffic if referrer is external

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-redirect, referrer

My old website is located in public_html. I have a new version of the site, which i installed in public_html/new/ .

I want to redirect all traffic from https://example.com to https:/example.com/new but i want to allow users to browse the old version (https://example.com) if they click a link from my new site.

Tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/.*
```

to match the referrer, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your complete rule/`.htaccess` file. That condition is OK. Have you confirmed the `Referer` header is being sent on the request? The Referer is unreliable, there are better ways to solve this if the old and new sites are on the same domain.

Comment: Presumably you aren’t intending to keep `/new` in the URL-path?

Comment: I want to keep the  /new particle.  I would gladly adopt any working solution.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/.* 
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/new/? [R=301,L]`

Comment: Do you want to redirect just the start page of the old site to the new one? Or would you want to redirect `https://example.com/i-am-an-old-page` to `/new/` as well?

Comment: I really can't see this making much sense right now. Assume I click on a link back to `https://example.com/` from your new page, in that case the referrer will be `https://example.com/new/...`, so that situation could be detected. But now I am navigating around _within_ the old page, I visit `https://example.com/some-old-page`, and there I click on the logo / home link or whatever, to take me to `https://example.com/` again. The referrer is not from the new site now, of course - so this would take me out of the old site at this point, and back to the new one ...

Comment: @CBroe "The referrer is not from the new site now" - That wouldn't matter. Providing the referrer is from the same domain, the condition is met.

Comment: @MrWhite hm, guess you are right, but I am still not convinced this kinda setup makes much sense to begin with. I'd have put the old site _into_ a folder `/old/`, then it can be browsed there without any referrer checks or anything else. And the new site would go under `/` directly, then it doesn't need any redirects to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, that would be much better.

Comment: @Cbroe I want to redirect https://example.com/i-am-an-old-page  and all other URLS's  of the old site to /new/ as well, as long as the referrer is outside of my domain.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://example.com/.*
> ​RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/new/? [R=301,L]
> ```

You've implemented this as a 301 (permanent) redirect (as it would need to be for SEO if you are migrating from an old to new site). However, the 301 redirect will be cached persistently by the browser. And redirect the user back to `/new` (from cache) without making a request to the server.

(This redirect also only redirects the old homepage. Inner pages are not redirected. Is that the intention?)

This would need to be a 302 (temporary) redirect - to avoid the redirect being cached, but that's not so good for SEO.

You could include a `?noredirect=1` parameter on URLs back to the old site (in the root) - a different URL - and only redirect when this param is not present. However, you would need to persist this URL param across all URLs having navigated from the new to old site. (And would allow anyone to access the old site by simply appending this URL param.)

However, @CBroe's suggestion in comments would be preferable. To move the old site to an `/old` subdirectory and the new site replaces the old site in the root. This would be better for SEO and users. Optionally, you could then simply *block* access to `/old` if the `Referer` is not the same domain (which would allow links from the new to old). And would prevent (most) bots from accessing `/old` (although you would still implement a `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP response header). Note, however, the `Referer` is unreliable and might not be set at all by some browsers (user's settings).